# A word that represents our department

Tags: single-word-requests

Would you kindly tell me a word for representing our department?

I have two guesses: system management department, and system supervising department (but both may not be correct here.)

I am working in a department where we survey the systems in our compamy continuously by a surveillance equipment.

If we find out some failure in them,  we replace the malfunctioned component and also make further investigation whether the failure is inherent in other devices so as to fix all of them. We also make plans to replace or augment the systems to extend their lifetime or improve theirs performances and ability.

We have a business meeting next week with engineers from oversea and I'd like to introduce my department to them.

Comment: I suggest that - sometime before your overseas visitors meet with you - your department gets together and decides what they wish to call themselves. Only yourselves know what it is you really do and only yourselves can decide what to call yourselves.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will propose our colleagues  to call our dept. as system management dept. 

Comment: Doesn't your department already have a meaningful name in your own language? If it does you could look for a translation of that name and ask whether the translation sounds natural and meaningful to us.

Comment: Yes you are right. I think system management dept. or system supervising dept. may be the translation literary.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this is the "Maintenance" department. Alternatively, the "Service and Support" department sounds appropriate as well. The three words could be combined in various permutations too.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use 'Oversight'. The word has two meanings: one is a mistake caused by not looking; the other is constant monitoring and supervision.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you think system oversighting department is ok ?

Answer (score 0):

Quality assurance or quality control?

Comment: Thank you for your advice. My company is a kind of infrastructure compamy, and our objective is to keep the equipmemt work well and provide our services continuously. In this case, can I use quality assurance or quarter control dept. for my department?